# Ajax posted php content not read by javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

GET-variable called `brand`.

A few hours ago when I had not implemented the ajax search box, everything worked fine.

The js part looks like this:

```
$('.mutliSelect input:checkbox').change(function() {

var brand = $("#brand_select input:checkbox:checked").map(function() {
return this.value;
}).get().join(',');


$(".submit_checkboxes").find("a").attr('href', 'index.php?brand=' + brand);
}).change();
```

Now, having implemented the ajax search box, the `var brand` does not seem to get filled with any value anymore.

This is the corresponding part of `index.php`:

```
<div class="mutliSelect" id="brand_select">
    <ul>
        <div class="search_view">
           <section class="drop_search">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Suche" id="search_brand" name="search_brand">
            </section>
        </div>

        <div id="results">
        //ajax-php result gets posted in here
        </div>

        <div class="button submit_checkboxes_button submit_checkboxes">
            <a href""><span>Anwenden</span></a>
        </div>          
    </ul>
</div>
```

and this is a part of `search.php` (this is the script that is called by ajax and posts the results):

```
 $result = mysql_query($query);
 while($brand = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

 echo 
    '<li><input type="checkbox" id="'.$brand['Brand'].'" value="'.$brand['Brand'].'"'; if(strpos($_SESSION['brand'],''.$brand['Brand'].'') !== false){ echo 'checked="checked"';} echo' />
     <label for="'.$brand['Brand'].'" class="checkbox_title">'.$brand['Brand'].'</label></li>';
```

It seems like the very last two lines (everything between `<li></li>` tags) does not get "noticed" by the upper js-function. When I put exactly these `<li></li>` tags into `index.php` - along with all php parts - however, it works fine.

Please let me know if this is clear. 
Does anybody have an idea on how to fix this issue?
Thank you!

ajax call:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

// Live Search
// On Search Submit and Get Results
function search() {
    var query_value = $('input#search_brand').val();
    $('b#search-string').text(query_value);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "php/search_brand.php",
            data: { query: query_value },
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
                $("div#results").html(html);
            }
        });
}

[...]
```

Comment: Can you provide the JS part that is responsible of updating the content of the 'result' div

Comment: you mean the ajax part? because apart from ajax, `js` only changes the `href` of a submit anchor, as you can see above

Comment: Are you sure your Ajax call is working ? You can check with Firebug plug-in what are the argument and return of the call

Comment: I will update my question to show the ajax call.